# Gradient Of $f(x,y)=2x^3+xy^2+5x^2+y^2$

Tags: calculus

If I am told to take the gradient of the function:$$f(x,y)=2x^3+xy^2+5x^2+y^2$$

So it is $F_{x}+F_{y}=0$?

Or in this case:

$$\{6x^2+y^2+10x\}+[2xy+2y]=0$$

And to find the critical points we take:

$F_{x}=0$ and $F_{y}=0$

Or in this case:

$6x^2+y^2+10x=0$ and $2xy+2y=0$

And the critical point are: $(1,\pm 2),(-\frac{5}{3},0),(0,0)$

Comment: I think you mean $(-1,\pm 2)$. But otherwise, those are the correct critical points... if I'm understanding your question??

Answer (score 5):

> So it is $F_{x}+F_{y}=0$?

No, the gradient of a function $f:ℝ^n→ℝ$ is defined as:
$$∇f(x_1,…,x_n)=\pmatrix{\frac{∂}{∂_{x_1}}f \\\vdots \\ \frac{∂}{∂_{x_n}}f}.$$

With $\frac{∂}{∂_{x_i}}$ denoting the partial derivative to $x_i$.

So in your case, for $f:ℝ^2→ℝ$, it is
$$∇f(x,y) = \pmatrix{\frac{∂}{∂_x}f(x,y) \\ \frac{∂}{∂_y}f(x,y)}.$$

So now you just need to calculate the derivatives. 
\begin{align*}
\frac{∂}{∂_x}f(x,y) &= \frac{∂}{∂_x}[2x^3+xy^2+5x^2+y^2] \\ 
&= 6x^2+y^2+10x \\ \\
\frac{∂}{∂_y}f(x,y) &= 2xy+2y
\end{align*}

edit: Since you want to calculate maxima and minima you are correct, that the necessary condition (just like in 1D) is:
$$∇f=0.$$
And that is short for 
$$\frac{∂}{∂_{x_i}} f = 0, \quad i=1,…,n$$
since the gradient is simply a vector.

But you also have to check that the second derivative is "$>0$" or "$<0$", just like in 1D. And now that we are talking about multivariate functions, the second derivative is a matrix, the so-called [Hessian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix), and "$\lessgtr 0$" is called definiteness.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test) illustrates that nice for the special 2D case and for arbitrary dimension.

Comment: @newhere I just edited my answer to better suit your quest for maxima/minima.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand why you consider the equation $f_x+f_y=0$.

But your critical points are correct.

Edit: it should read $(-1,\pm 2)$.

Comment: Yes missed the minus